# Error in compilation in Angular class while using ng serve

Tags: angular, angular7

I have class Todo component class.While doing ng serve I am able to run the project but I am seeing the error in command prompt:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { TodoDataService } from '../service/data/todo-data.service';
    import { Todo } from '../list-todos/list-todos.component';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-todo',
      templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
    })
    export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {

      id:number
      todo:Todo

      constructor(
        private todoService: TodoDataService,
        private route:ActivatedRoute,
        private router :Router
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.id=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

        this.todo=new Todo(this.id,'',false,new Date());

        if(this.id != -1){
            this.todoService.retrieveTodo('in28minutes',this.id)
            .subscribe(
            data => this.todo=data
            )
        }

      }

      saveToDo(){
        console.log("before entering"+this.id);
        if(this.id == -1){
      //create todo
     console.log("here at create");
      this.todoService.createTodo('in28minutes',this.todo).subscribe(

        data => console.log(data)
        this.router.navigate(['todos'])
        )
        }
        else{
       //update todo
          console.log(this.id);
          console.log("here at update");
          this.todoService.updateTodo('in28minutes',this.id,this.todo).subscribe(

            data => console.log(data)
            this.router.navigate(['todos'])
          )
      }
    }
    }
```

While compiling and running I am getting error as.I have reviewed this class but I am not seeing any comma needed in there.

[image]

The red markers are shown in navigate part of code:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post text, not pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because of the way you are using subscribe, it needs to be a function but since you are not wrapping your code into {} its being seen as two parameters(response and error). You should take a look at the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables).

The compilation is telling you that you have two errors and it looks like its the exact same code for both errors.

Replace your subscribe with:

```
this.todoService.createTodo('in28minutes',this.todo).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.router.navigate(['todos'])
  }
);
```